# How to show variations order for each different product in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I mean not the order in attributes-terms for all products, like xs-s-m-l-xl for all. I mean exactly for one separate product. For example in one product the red color has to be the first, yellow the second and blue the third, in other separate product green has to be the first, blue the second, etc. I drag and drop variations in admin bar in variations tab, and in admin bar it's showing as I do, but on the front end in product they are still showing alphabetically. I don't need alphabetical order, how to change it? Is there a code snippet for it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think it could be worded better if you used the word "variation" instead of "separate product" and then use "product" instead of "all products". The admin bar is the black bar at the top of the page. If you can't find a solution to this you could use JavaScript to change the order.